# Url stored in MySQL returns with extra backslash for each forward slash ( a/b.png => a\/b.png)

Tags: php, mysql, backslash

I have a MySql database with a URL field that has normal URLs with forward slashes. When I get the URL data with PHP web service it shows up with a backward slash for each forward slash:

```
http://example.com/iphone/images/test.png
```

shows as

```
http:\/\/example.com\/iphone\/images\/test.png
```

What could be the problem?

---

Here is the function that gets my data.

```
function getdata() {

    // Check for required parameters
    if (isset($_POST["genre"])) {

        // Put parameters into local variables
        $genre = $_POST["genre"];

        // Final result array
        $final_result = array();

        // Look up in database
        $user_id = 0;
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT ID, BAND, VENUE, GENRE, DATE, THUMBNAIL_URL, DESCRIPTION FROM shows WHERE GENRE=?');
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $genre);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $band_result, $venue_result, $genre, $date, $thumbnail_url, $description);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {


            $thumbnail_url = stripslashes($thumbnail_url);

            $result = array(
            "id" => $id, "band" => $band_result, "venue" => $venue_result, "genre" => $genre, "date" => $date, "thumbnail_url" => $thumbnail_url, "description" => $description,
            );
            $final_result[] = $result;
            continue;
        }
        $stmt->close();





        sendResponse(200, json_encode($final_result));
        return true;
    }
    sendResponse(400, 'Invalid request');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this can happen is your host most likely has **[magic_quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php)** enabled and it can change from host to host. *(a futile attempt to strengthen security by escaping user submitted inputs)*.

So its always best to check if its enabled. *(especially if your script reaches other configurations)*

Then if so handle the stripping of thos unwanted extra slashes before you insert into database, still always use **[mysql_real_escape_sting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)** or **[PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)** to escape into the database else errors or [mysql injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) will follow.

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  $genre = stripslashes($_POST["genre"]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's showing up in the database with slashes; that's fine.

If you want to remove them in your PHP after getting them out of the database, run it through stripslashes();

```
$url = stripslashes($url);
```

If you want to strip the slashes before it goes into the database... same as above, but think twice before you do :)