# Should I try to rid my MySQL database of back-slashes?

Tags: mysql, magic-quotes-gpc

I'm using PDO prepared statements to insert data into a MySQL database, and I notice that apostrophes (single quotes) in strings are being stored in the database with back-slashes (`\`) preceding them.

I use `stripslashes($string)` on output, and of course this gets rid of them.

I searched my server's `phpinfo()` information (PHP version 5.2.17) for "magic_quotes" and found:

- magic_quotes_gpc: local value = on, master value = on
- magic_quotes_runtime: local value = off, master value = off
- magic_quotes_sybase: local value = off, master value = off

**Firstly**, would turning magic_quotes_gpc off prevent the occurrence of the back-slashes?  I don't currently have access to the server php.ini master settings, but as I understand it I would be able to disable it by configuring the root .htaccess file with the directive `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off`.

**Secondly**, is the prevention of these back-slashes in the database desirable?  I ask this because I saw the somewhat cryptic remark [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7356010) to "*think twice before you do*".

Answer (score 2):

> would turning magic_quotes_gpc off prevent the occurrence of the back-slashes?

Probably yes.

> is the prevention of these back-slashes in the database desirable?

Yes. They serve no purpose. If you use PDO and properly parametrized queries, the problem that  magic quotes used to address is already solved.

See [the PHP manual on magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) on why they were used, and why they should no longer be used.

Comment: Thank you for that helpful clarification.

Comment: Hmm.. turning `magic_quotes_gpc` off by use of the .htaccess directive didn't work - not sure why.  The phpinfo() now shows the local value to be off, but db insertions still result in back-slashes in the database.  I don't know why this is, so I guess I'll have to use `stripslashes()` before insertion (though don't you have to use it multiple times for repeated apostrophes?).

Comment: @John hmm, strange. Can you check whether you have any `addslashes()` calls anywhere?

Comment: Well, I've disabled `magic_quotes_gpc` yet the strings in the db still have slashes before quotes. Can someone tell me - does PDO add these in any ways?

Comment: @John nope, it shouldn't. Is there any other sanitation function being applied like `mysql_real_escape_string()`? Something with `escape` in it?

Comment: No, nothing like that. I'm wondering if it's the server erroneously reporting the `magic_quotes_gpc` setting, as set out here:  [link](http://drupal.org/node/1437998) ... long shot!